# MySQL ORDER BY letters then numbers

Tags: mysql

I have MySQL Query with an ORDER BY that looks like this:

```
ORDER BY home_status = 2, home_lot_size, home_status ASC, home_price
```

Now the home_lot_size can either be Townhome, 30, 36, 40, 46, 50 but the order comes out like this, 30, 36, 40, 46, 50 and then Townhome, I am looking to get Townhome at the top then 30, 36, 40, 46, 50

is this possible?

Comment: Is **Townhome**  only string in your table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a CASE clause to create a new column you can sort on. Something like this

```
SELECT 
  CASE home_lot_size
    WHEN 'Townhome' THEN '00'
    ELSE home_lot_size
  END as sort_by
FROM table
ORDER BY sort_by
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution,

```
SELECT * FROM your_table_name WHERE (home_lot_size='Townhome' OR 1=1) ORDER BY home_lot_size='Townhome' DESC
```

You don't need to use case for this.

Comment: I did not even knew you could do that with order by +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CASE`in the `ORDER BY`:

```
ORDER BY home_status = 2, 
         case when home_lot_size = 'Townhome' then '0' else home_lot_size end, 
         home_status ASC, home_price
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. One quick fix would be to have `home_lot_size` evaluated in a numeric context, such that the value of `Townhome` would be evaluated as zero, and the other values as integers. An easy way to do that is to add zero, e.g.

```
ORDER BY home_status = 2, home_lot_size + 0, home_status, home_price 
                                        ^^^
```

In the more general case, we could use a more complex series of expressions, e.g.

```
ORDER BY home_status = 2
       , IF(home_lot_size='Townhome',0,1)
       , home_lot_size
       , home_status
       , home_price
```